# Can i change the label 'Employees' in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I just want to change the label 'Employees' which is showing on the Employees(hr) module into 'Staffs' in Odoo 10. How can i achieve this ??

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Where? menu, view?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="hr.menu_hr_root">
      <field name="name">My New Menu Name</field>
</record>
```

**> This way you can change the menu name.**

Answer (score 0):

You can achive by ading xpath like this:

```
<field name="employee_id" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="string">Staffs</attribute>
</field>
```